# Reinitialize JetPack Lazy Load

Tags: ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading, jetpack

I am using JetPack on my WordPress site, and have lazy loading enabled. However, in my site I update some content with AJAX, and this results in loading the 1x1 placeholder of images, rather than the true image, which the lazy load would handle.

How do I call lazy loading again, using Jet Pack? I seem to recall there being a JavaScript function, but can't find what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
$(document.body).trigger('post-load');
```

It triggers a jQuery event that the lazy load module is listening for to lazy load images from infinite scroll.

Comment: Awesome!!! I'll have to try it out the next time I need this again (I've moved on from that previous project from March).

Comment: Just had a chance to use it on a new project, and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.